# Como fazer para que um form surja na tela ao clicar num link?

Tags: html

Estou tentando fazer com que meu form apareça no espaço em branco ao lado quando eu clico no link **"DIGITAR GUIA DE CONSULTA"**. 
Já tentei algo como: (mas não tive o resultado esperado)

```
   <frameset cols="100%">
         <frame src="link da página aqui"></frame>           
       </frameset>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem essa opção... Veja se ajuda.

```css
.lightbox {
 /** Esconde a classe lightbox */
 display: none;
 /** Estilo basico para a classe */
}
.lightbox:target {
    /** Aplica essa regras quando target ocorre na classe */
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
}
a{
    display:block;
}
input{
float:left;
}
.close{
    /**Classe para fechar a div, se quiser*/
    display:inline;
    padding-left:7px;
}
```

```html
<header>Digitação de Guias</header>
<hr/>
<a href="#content">Digitar Guia de Consulta</a>
<div id="content" class="lightbox">
  <form id="form_1">
      <input type="text" value="Nome"/><br/>
      <input type="text" value="Email"/>
      <input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
      <a class="close" href="#">X</a> 
  </form>
</div>
<a href="outro_form">Digitar Guia de Exames</a>
<a href="e_outro">Avisos Importantes</a>
```

Qualquer coisa comenta que ajustamos.

Comment: No caso, meu form é feito em uma página, e a minha página restrita é em outra. Explicando melhor.. Quando o usuário fizer o login, será direcionado para a página restrita. Nessa página restrita, contém o link para digitar a guia de consulta. (A Guia de Consulta é feita em uma página, pois a ideia era que ao clicar no link "guia de consulta", abrir uma janela na qual contém o form). Mas agora preciso fazer com que ao clicar no link, surja o form no espaço em branco. E essa opção que você me deu, não faz isso.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar `<iframe>` ou ainda pode fazer uma requisição em ajax com jquery para isso segue abaixo link de tutorial para as duas verções

```
<iframe src="paginaembranco.html" name="meuIframe"></iframe>
<a href="http://google.com" target="meuIframe">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

ou para jquery com ajax
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: se deu certo marque como concluído , caso tenha mais dúvidas m avise.

Comment: Se fosse pra deixar o form fixo na parte em branco do site, seria muito útil. Mas não ficou do jeito que eu gostaria.

Comment: manda o link ou ss de como ficou e explique como vc gostaria que funcionasse

Comment: Eu não tenho nenhum site como exemplo. Vou tentar explicar o máximo possível. Eu tenho uma página onde ao clicar num link "digitar guia de consulta", o formulário a ser preenchido apareça no espaço em branco da tela.

Comment: sim com iframe funciona certinho , no espaço em branco vc cria um iframe sem bordas do tamanho do espaço em branco quando vc clikar no link vc carrega um outro html com o formulario dentro do iframe

Comment: Eu fiz conforme me explicou ali em cima, e apareceu o form dentro do iframe.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45013/discussion-between-inez-boldrin-and-jasar-orion).